# How to solve a problem with Python unable to import name from module?

Tags: python, c#

I want to load a model that was trained in Wing with python to Visual studio where I use c#. After doing this (trying to load this KERAS model to vs):

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string PYTHONHOME = @"C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311";
    string PYTHONPATH = @"C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", PYTHONHOME, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", PYTHONHOME, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", PYTHONPATH, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    var _model= Keras.Models.Model.LoadModel(@"C:\Users\...\net.h5"); 
}
```

I end up with this error by Python:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\lib\io.py", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)
```

Tried to delete name 'text_encoding' from 'io' but that brought back more errors so I don't know what to do now. Any ideas how to fix this? Also tried reinstalling Python and it didn't help

Comment: I just think that solving this error might finally let the model load in my project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you sure kearas.net works with python 3.11? It says requires 3.7 or 3.8 on their website (https://github.com/SciSharp/Keras.NET) and it doesn't seem to have been updated recently

Comment: Thank you! You are right, I downloaded python 3.7 and the problem solved. Now there are some new, bit I'll try to fix them)